# React hook form - passing an array of strings as constant to useWatch not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I would like to watch some fields in my component, but would like to make sure I pass in a constant as an array, so that I make sure the order of fields is kept the same through the app, so that I know which fields have been updated.
I have tried to do it very simply like this:

```
export enum FieldsToWatch {
    "firstField",
    "secondField",
}

const fieldsBeingWatched = useWatch({
    control,
    name: Object.keys(FieldsToWatch),
});
```

But, that throw typescript error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
```

If I just pass an array like this:

```
const fieldsBeingWatched = useWatch({
    control,
    name: ['firstField', 'secondField'],
});
```

Then I don't get a compile error, but I would like to do this is in a type safe way. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I think type safety by using `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()` will work